# Guidelines on how to use ByteBuddy correctly and efficiently

Tags: bytecode, instrumentation, byte-buddy

I looked at ByteBuddy documentation and have also looked at few of the Java Agent implementations that are using ByteBuddy. But I am still not very clear on what is the right way to use the ByteBuddy agent.

This is the code I used to bootstrap my agent:

```
public class ByteBuddyAgent {

    public static void premain(String arguments, Instrumentation instrumentation) {

        System.out.println("Bootstrapping ByteBuddy Agent");


        new AgentBuilder.Default()
                .with(new AgentBuilder.InitializationStrategy.SelfInjection.Eager())
                .type(ElementMatchers.hasSuperClass(ElementMatchers.nameContains("Level1")))
                .transform(new ByteBuddyTransformer()
                .installOn(instrumentation);

    }

    private static class ByteBuddyTransformer implements AgentBuilder.Transformer{

        @Override
        public DynamicType.Builder<?> transform(DynamicType.Builder<?> builder, TypeDescription typeDescription,
                                                ClassLoader classLoader, JavaModule module) {

            return builder.method(ElementMatchers.named("printLevel"))
                    .intercept(Advice.to(MethodTracker.class));
        }
    }
}
```

This is my Advice class where I have tried different annotations supported by Advice and it worked fine.

```
public class MethodTracker {

    @Advice.OnMethodEnter
    public static Object onMethodBegin(@Advice.This Object invokedObject, @Advice.AllArguments Object[] arguments,
                                       @Advice.FieldValue("name") Object fieldValue, @Advice.Origin Object origin,
                                       @Advice.Local("localVariable") Object localVariable) {
        System.out.println("=======on Method Begin Running with ByteBuddy=======, " + invokedObject);
        System.out.println("======Printing arguments=======");
        for(Object obj: arguments){
            System.out.println("Argument:: " + obj);
        }
        localVariable = "Gunika";

        System.out.println("FieldValue:: " + fieldValue);
        System.out.println("Origin:: " + origin);
        return "ReturningStateFromOnMethodBegin";
    }

    @Advice.OnMethodExit(onThrowable = Throwable.class, suppress = Throwable.class)
    public static void onMethodEnd(@Advice.This Object invokedObject, @Advice.Return Object returnValue,
                                   @Advice.FieldValue("name") Object fieldValue, @Advice.Enter Object state,
                                   @Advice.Local("localVariable") Object localVariable){
        System.out.println("=======on Method End Running with ByteBuddy======= " + invokedObject);

        System.out.println("Return value is " + returnValue);
        System.out.println("FieldValue:: " + fieldValue);
        System.out.println("FieldValue:: " + fieldValue);
        System.out.println("State:: " + state);
        System.out.println("LocalVariable:: " + localVariable);
    }
}
```

The questions that I have are as follows:

- Right now in my sample app, I have just tried matching with 1 rule.
  But if there are “n” rules that I want to apply what is the right away to achieve that.
- There are initial set of rules that are applied/provided to the agent. Now let's say at some point of time I want to add another rule. What is the correct way to achieve that?
- Does the AgentBuilder instance that we create should be created only once in the Java Agent?
- Any other information that should be taken care while using ByteBuddy agent would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

`Advice.to(MethodTracker.class)` is pretty expensive. If you instrument many classes and want to spend the memory, I'd recommend you to reuse the instance, it is immutable.

Other than that, `@Advice.AllArguments` is more expensive than using specialized advice classes that read particular arguments, if you can afford it. This is however rather a JVM question than a Byte Buddy-specific one. You can use `-Dnet.bytebuddy.dump=/some/folder` to see what byte code is generated. Expensiveness often lies burried what constructs you go for.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @rafael. Few more clarifications: I was also trying to debug my Advice class i.e MethodTracker. I am not able to do that meaning the debug point never comes there. I saw the transformer class and it seemed that instead of putting  MethodTracker class, the code inside it is copied to the transformed class. Is there a way to change that? Secondly what about trying to add rules dynamically, how should I do that?.

Comment: You can set `delegate = true` in the advice annotation but this only works with visible class loaders, it can help with debugging, though. Other than that, the advice code is a template and never actually executed.